# UPDATE: XML Parsing Error: junk after document element Location: PHP

Tags: php, xml-parsing

I'm getting a Error. XML Parsing Error: junk after document element Locationhttp://localhost/fcdemo/get-data.php?year=2012 Line Number 2, Column 1

```
Undefined index: type in C:\EasyPHP-12.1\www\fcdemo\get-data.php on line 3.
Undefined index: month in C:\EasyPHP-12.1\www\fcdemo\get-data.php on line 5.
Undefined index: day in C:\EasyPHP-12.1\www\fcdemo\get-data.php on line 6.
```

I'm looking on lines 3, 5 and 6 still can't figure it out.

Here is my code.

```
    <?php
    //Sanitizing the input
    $Type   = $_GET['type'];
    $Year   = intval($_GET['year']);
    $Month  = intval($_GET['month']);
    $Day    = intval($_GET['day']);

    //Months Names
    $MonthsNames = array(null, 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec');

    //Prepare variables according to type-of-chart
    switch($Type)
    {
        default:
        case 'monthly':
            $Query = "SELECT MONTH(Time) AS Value, COUNT(*) AS Total FROM `users` WHERE YEAR(Time)={$Year} GROUP BY Value";
            $ResultArray = array_fill(1, 12, 0); // fill the Result array with 0 values for each month
            $ChartHeading = 'Monthly New Users for the Year: '.$Year;
            $XaxisName = 'Months';
            break;

        case 'daily':
            $Query = "SELECT DAY(Time) AS Value, count(*) AS Total FROM `users` WHERE YEAR(Time)={$Year} AND MONTH(Time)={$Month} GROUP BY Value";
            $ResultArray = array_fill(1, 31, 0);  // fill the Result array with 0 values for each day
            $ChartHeading = 'Daily New Users for the Month: '.$MonthsNames[$Month].'/'.$Year;
            $XaxisName = 'Days';
            break;

        case 'hourly':
            $Query = "select HOUR(Time) AS Value, count(*) AS Total FROM `users` WHERE YEAR(Time)={$Year} AND MONTH(Time)={$Month} AND DAY(Time)={$Day} GROUP BY Value";
            $ResultArray = array_fill(0, 24, 0);   // fill the Result array with 0 values for each hour
            $ChartHeading = 'Hourly New Users for the Date: '.$Day.'/'.$MonthsNames[$Month].'/'.$Year;
            $XaxisName = 'Hours';
            break;
    }

    //Connect to database
    require 'connect-to-database.php';

    //Query the database
    $QueryResult = mysql_query($Query);

    //Fetch results in the Result Array
    while($Row = mysql_fetch_assoc($QueryResult))
        $ResultArray[$Row['Value']]=$Row['Total'];

    //Generate Chart XML: Head Part
    $Output = '<chart caption="'.$ChartHeading.'" xAxisName="'.$XaxisName.'" yAxisName="Users" showNames="1" bgColor="E6E6E6,F0F0F0" bgAlpha="100,50" bgRatio="50,100" bgAngle="270" showBorder="1" borderColor="AAAAAA" baseFontSize="12">';

    //Generate Chart XML: Main Body
    switch($Type)
    {
        default:
        case 'monthly':
            foreach($ResultArray as $MonthNumber => $value)  // MonthNumber is month number (1-12)
                $Output .= '<set value="'.$value.'" name="'.$MonthsNames[$MonthNumber].'" link="newchart-xmlurl-get-data.php?type=daily&amp;year='.$Year.'&amp;month='.$MonthNumber.'"/>';
            break;
        case 'daily':
            foreach($ResultArray as $DayNumber => $value)  // DayNumber is day (1-31)
                $Output .= '<set value="'.$value.'" name="'.$DayNumber.'" link="newchart-xmlurl-get-data.php?type=hourly&amp;year='.$Year.'&amp;month='.$Month.'&amp;day='.$key.'"/>';
            break;
        case 'hourly':
            foreach($ResultArray as $HourNumber => $value)  // HourNumber is hour (0-23)
                $Output .= '<set value="'.$value.'" name="'.$HourNumber.'"/>';
            break;
    }

    //Generate Chart XML: Last Part
    $Output .= '</chart>';

    //Set the output header to XML
    header('Content-type: text/xml');

    //Send output
    echo $Output;
?>
```

Comment: You need to pass 'type', 'month' and 'day' in your $_GET array, otherwise you'll get those errors. You are only passing the 'year' variable in the URL. If they are optional, use `if(isset($_GET['type']))`... etc.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved Thank you

I change it to: Changed to:

```
$Month = (isset($_GET['month']) && is_numeric($_GET['month']))?$_GET['month']:date("n");
$Year = (isset($_GET['year']) && is_numeric($_GET['year']))?$_GET['year']:date("Y");
$Day = (isset($_GET['day']) && is_numeric($_GET['day']))?$_GET['day']:date("d");
$Type   = (isset($_GET['type']) ? $_GET['type'] : NULL);
```

Comment: if resolved, accept your answer, i guess, so it would not be lingering in unanswered queue.